# Como multiplicar los valores en inputs y sumar los totales con separadores de mil y decimales?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla con inputs dentro que corresponden a una factura o recibo. Esta un input de cantidad, precio y total. Quisiera poder multiplicar cantidad * precio y resultado colocarlo en el total, hasta ese punto no es complicado, pero resulta que tengo separadores de mil en este formato = "1,000.00", se escriben de derecha a izquierda en el input y no encuentro como hacerlo con los separadores.

Ademas como son varias filas en necesario que lo totales se sumen y se agregue en el total general. Esto lo hago ya pero cuando activo los separadores solo toma en cuenta el numero antes de la coma y lo demas no.

Quiero saber como hacerlo, me serviria tambien que solo se sumen con dos decimales y siempre puedan aparecer en este formato "1000.00" tambien es factible.

```js
  $("#precio,#total,#total-suma").on({
        "focus": function (event) {
            $(event.target).select();
        },
        "keyup": function (event) {
            $(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
                return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                            .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
                            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
            });
        }
    });

    items = document.getElementsByClassName("total-input")

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    n = document.getElementById("total-suma");
    n.value = parseFloat("0"+n.value) + parseFloat("0"+this.value) - parseFloat("0"+this.defaultValue);
   this.defaultValue = this.value;
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="bordes-tabla-venta">
     <tr>
      <th class="td-border">
       <p class="head-tab-ventas">CANT</p>
      </th>
      <th class="td-border">
       <p class="head-tab-ventas">DESCRIPCION</p>
      </th>
      <th class="td-border">
       <p class="head-tab-ventas">PREC. UNIT.</p>
      </th>
      <th class="td-border">
       <p class="head-tab-ventas">TOTAL</p>
      </th>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off" ></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off" ></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off" ></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
  
     <tr>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="number" id="cantidad" class="cantidad-input"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" class="descripcion-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="precio" class="precio-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total" class="total-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
  
      <tr>
      <td class="td-border"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border total-a-pagar"><strong><p>TOTAL A PAGAR</p></strong></td>
      <td class="td-border"><input type="text" id="total-suma" class="total-input" autocomplete="off"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que he entendido bien tu pregunta y lo he resuelto sin usar jquery, solo js. 
He realizado la parte de la suma total de un producto (precio * cantidad).

Para sumar el precio, simplemnte quito las comas del numero y las multiplico por la cantidad, para las decimales utilizo `toFixed`, aunque hay muchas más opciones.

Simplemente añade eso a tu codigo, aparte de lo que hay, y mira como funciona

Una cosa, intenta evitar usar id's iguales, por norma general no se tienen que repetir.

Espero que te sirva

```js
        //suma de precio unitario
        //cuando modificamos el precio unitario
        var patron1 = /([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/;
        var patron2 = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g;
        for(let precioUnitario of document.getElementsByClassName("precio-input")){
            precioUnitario.addEventListener("change", function(){
                let precio = (this.value).replace(/,/g, "");
                let cantidad = this.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.firstChild.value;
                this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].firstChild.value = (Number(precio) * cantidad).toFixed(2).replace(patron1, '$1.$2').replace(patron2, ",");
            totalAPagar();
            });
        }
        
        //cuando modificamos la cantidad
        for(let cantidad of document.getElementsByClassName("cantidad-input")){
            cantidad.addEventListener("change", function(){
                let cantidad = this.value;
                let precio = (this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value).replace(/,/g, "");
                // console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].firstChild.value);
                this.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].firstChild.value = (Number(precio) * cantidad).toFixed(2).replace(patron1, '$1.$2').replace(patron2, ",");
            totalAPagar();
            });
        }

//suma total a pagar
    //recorremos cada uno y cuando haya cambio en uno de ellos hacemos la suma
    function totalAPagar() {
        //cuando haya cambio en UNO de los totales hacemos la suma total
        var sumaTotal = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("total-input").length - 1; i++) {
            let precioTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("total-input")[i];
            //cogemos los precios y le quitamos las comas (para hacer la suma bien)
            let precio = (precioTotal.value).replace(/,/g, "");
            sumaTotal += Number(precio);
        }
        //una vez tenemos todos los precios, los metemos en el campo TOTAL A PAGAR y le damos formato
        document.getElementById("total-suma").value = sumaTotal.toFixed(2)
            .replace(patron1, '$1.$2').replace(patron2, ",");
    }
```

Comment: Excelente e verdad funciona muy bien, ya lo probé muchas gracias. Ahora la multiplicacion de precio * cantidad = total-input lo hace perfecto.
Trato de sumar todos los .total-input para que el resultado se inserte en #total-suma pero no puedo

Comment: Lo de los id's tienes razón, lo cambiaré, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirva! Para `#total-suma` simplemente recrea lo que hice yo, coge todos los `total-input`, quitas las comas y los sumas.

Comment: Hola de nuevo men, he tratado pero no logro hacerlo, la verdad que en este punto de js me pierdo ya que estoy aprendiendo js apenas. Agradeceria tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Cuando se ejecuten `onchange` de la cantidad y el precio unitario, intenta hacer una funcion que te haga la suma total de todo. Igualmente modififcare mi respuesta antigua para poner la suma totalitaria.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, de verdad, bueno sigue sin sumar los .total-input, trate de agregar algo debajo de la ejecucion de onchange pero me sale "NaN" en total-suma

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta que la modifique para que te haga la suma y funciona, lo he comprobado, simplemente pega ese trozo de script a tu código

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona, lo estudiare bien para entenderlo. Mil gracias bro

Comment: Cualquier duda pregunta!